# React & nginx routing to subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, nginx

Just started with using React. I have an app created with `create-react-app` which should be running on a `sub-directory` while making API calls to a different path.

**React App:**

location on server: `/var/www/myapp/build`

endpoint: `https://foo.example.com/analytics`

**Data API endpoint:** `https://foo.example.com/api/data`

**Nginx setup**

```
    location /analytics {
           root /var/www/myapp/build;
           try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
```

When setting `"homepage":"https://foo.example.com/analytics"` in the client's `package.json`, all the resource paths seem to be correct (i.e. `https://foo.example.com/analytics/static/...`), but when checking networking no request to `.../api/data` shows up in my browser's networking inspector and the app doesn't properly spawn.

Using absolute paths in the `App's API call` (`fetch('https://foo.example.com/api/data')` instead of `fetch('/api/data')`) doesn't seem to help, either.

When instead I set `"homepage":"."` in `package.json` and also change the Nginx config to serve the react build directory on server root, the app works.

```
server {
        root /var/www/myapp/build;
}
```

However, in this case, the app is also available under `https://foo.example.com`, which is something I don't want.

I strongly suspect this has to do with routing, but couldn't figure out how to fix it. So any help would be much appreciated!

**--- Edit / Solution ---**

I doubt it's the most straight forward solution, but the following setup works for me:

**React App**

In `package.json`, set `"homepage":"./analytics"` before running `npm run build`

**Nginx config:**

```
    location =  /analytics {

            root /var/www/myapp/build;
            try_files /index.html =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/analytics(.*) {

            root /var/www/myapp/build;
            try_files $1 $1/ /index.html =404;
    }
```

My understanding is that the initial setup using `try_files $uri` was looking for files in the root directory `/var/www/myapp/build` for the full uri rather than only the path that follows `/analytics`. E.g. when requesting `../analytics/css/styles.css` it would check if a file (or directory) is available under `/var/www/mayapp/build/analytics/css/styles.css` which doesn't exist, so it kept serving the `index.html` as fallback. Hence the regex workaround.

Feedback to improve this solution still very welcome, though.

Answer (score 52):

I was struggling with the same problem. Finally I was able to solve it using official documentation and a combination of answers:

Assumptions:

- Your React App is based on `create-react-app` package (you are using `react-router-dom`).
- You are using Nginx and the root path is being used by another service (or even another React/Gatsby App which is my case).
- You want to deploy the React App on a subdirectory and be able to serve all statics of your React App from that subdirectory.

**React App Changes**:

Based on [official documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths).

1. Update your `BrowserRouter` by adding a `basename`. Example: `<BrowserRouter history={history} basename="/webapp">`.
2. Specify a `homepage` on your `package.json`. Example: `"homepage": "/webapp"`.
3. If you are referencing a static file by its relative path, you should add the subdirectory to that reference. Example: `src="/static/logo/logo.png"` becomes `src="/webapp/static/logo/logo.png"`.

**Nginx Changes**:

```
location ^~ /webapp {
   alias /var/www/myapp/build;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /webapp/index.html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this step-by-step solution. If anyone wonders: you don't need to use anything of the router, simply adding the <BrowserRouter basename="/webapp"> to your root app is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks alot. I can second Ursin's comment as well.

Comment: not all heroes wear capes...

Comment: **Deploy Reactjs & Laravel with subdirectory using NGINX**
in this GitHub repo, I define both reactjs and laravel configuration and attached the real configuration file.
https://github.com/SyedAsadRazaDevops/How-to-Deploy-Reactjs-and-Laravel-with-subdirectory-using-NGINX

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of nginx location configuration:

```
location ^~ /analytics  {
    alias /var/www/myapp/build;

    subs_filter href="/ href="http://foo.example.com/analytics;
    subs_filter src="/ src="http://foo.example.com/analytics;
}
```

- The `location` is set to `^~ /analytics` , meaning that the rules    created in the location braces will become effective when somebody visits http://foo.example.com/analytics
- The `alias` is set to the static build folder of create-react-app site `/var/www/myapp/build`. That’ll be served when the visitor hits your subdirectory url foo.example.com/analytics
- Next, the two `subs_filter` lines replace any reference to `href` and `src` urls that start with the React app’s home directory `/` with the new complete URL. That will ensure all your CSS and JS files are located and served correctly by NGINX.

The final thing, in the case of Create-React-App is that any references to `createBrowserHistory` in your react router need to be replaced by `createHashHistory`, as Browser History won’t work with the above NGINX configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to replicate your nginx location config. Both as you wrote it and with closing closing quotation marks (e.g. `subs_filter href="/"` ..) but in both cases I get an error when running `nginx -t`

Comment: Your answer is missing some quotes

Comment: It is always nice to refer to the original source when quoting it in an answer. Here it is http://graemefulton.com/code/snippet/nginx-configurations-to-run-create-react-app-from-a-subdirectory-of-wordpress.

Comment: The original domain is down, here is a wayback machine link: https://web.archive.org/web/20191001055835/http://graemefulton.com/code/snippet/nginx-configurations-to-run-create-react-app-from-a-subdirectory-of-wordpress.

Comment: ^ `sub_filter href="/" href="https://api.example.com/some-sub-dir";` - no `s` in `sub` (NOT `subs`) [EDIT: Hey, this worked me woot! I searched everywhere]

Answer (score 4):

My website is called derekdawsonspersonalwebsite.com and I wanted to serve a react app I made at derekdawsonspersonalwebsite.com/metronome/

I got this working by doing the following:

1. Added `"homepage": "/metronome",` to the `package.json` file
2. If you are using react router, add `<BrowserRouter basename="/your_subdirectory">`, in my case:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/metronome">
    <div>
        <nav>
            <Link to="/"></Link>
        </nav>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Metronome} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

3. `yarn run build`
4. I uploaded the contents of the build directory to this location on my server `/var/www/personalwebsite.com/metronome`
5. This is what my server block `/etc/nginx/sites-available/personalwebsite.com` looks like

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name derekdawsonspersonalwebsite.com www.derekdawsonspersonalwebsite.com;
    ssl_certificate /home/derek/ssl/derekdawsonspersonalwebsite.com_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/derek/ssl/derekdawsonspersonalwebsite.com_tld.key;

    location / {
        root /var/www/personalwebsite.com;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /metronome {
        root /var/www/personalwebsite.com;
        index index.html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name derekdawsonspersonalwebsite.com www.derekdawsonspersonalwebsite.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: You are not using a nested directory after Metronome. You will get an error if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to get it working

1. While creating build for application assign subdirectory to PUBLIC_URL.

```
 PUBLIC_URL=/analytics/ npm run build --production
```

2. Inside nginx.conf add

```
 location /analytics {
            # Maps /analytics to /
            rewrite ^/analytics$ / break;

            # Maps /analytics/.. to /..
            rewrite ^/analytics(/.*) $1 break;  
          
            try_files $uri /index.html =404;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Juan García](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6883240/juan-garc%C3%ADa), in my case i was using vite and added

> base: "/webapp"

in vite.config.ts file instead of adding homepage in package.json