# nginx-ingress sending traffic to nginx in pod but not returning assets

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-location, nginx-ingress

Basically, I'm having difficulty getting `nginx` to serve the `npm build` from a CRA web app that is at the subpath `/new-admin`.

I do have in the `package.json` `"homepage": "/new-admin"` and `<Route basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>` in the `index.js`. Works fine in development, but now that I'm trying to make a staging/production copy it isn't and I'm pretty sure it is due to the `./nginx/default.conf`. Of the various configurations I've tried, none have worked and I either get:

- `500 Internal Server Error`
- `<Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

This is what I have:

```
# ingress.yaml

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "500m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^(/admin)$ $1/ permanent;
  name: ingress-service-dev-admin
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /admin/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: admin-old-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 4000  
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^(/new-admin)$ $1/ permanent;
  name: ingress-service-dev
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /new-admin/
            backend:
              serviceName: admin-new-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 4001
          - path: /api/
            backend:
              serviceName: api-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 5000
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 3000
```

```
# Dockerfile for /new-admin/

FROM node:13-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 4001
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

This version of the `default.conf` results in a `500 Internal Server Error`:

```
# ./nginx/default.conf

server {
  listen 4001;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location /new-admin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /new-admin/index.html;
  }
}
```

This is the associated `nginx` log:

```
[admin-new] 2020/10/05 20:31:49 [error] 28#28: *9 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/new-admin/index.html", client: 172.17.0.4, server: , request: "GET /new-admin/ HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.64.5"
[admin-new] 172.17.0.4 - - [05/Oct/2020:20:31:49 +0000] "GET /new-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36" "192.168.64.1"
```

This version results in `<Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`:

```
# ./nginx/default.conf

server {
  listen 4001;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

This seems closest to being correct given it serves the `index.html`, just not the CSS and JS assets. It does show in the `index.html`, which should be correct:

```
<script src="/new-admin/static/js/2.c6b4376b.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/new-admin/static/js/main.c24347bf.chunk.js"></script>
```

I've also noticed when it starts the Pod it says, despite the fact it is building the images from scratch.

```
[admin-new] /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
[admin-new] /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
[admin-new] /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
[admin-new] 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
[admin-new] 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: error: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
[admin-new] /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
[admin-new] /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, came across this answer which was pretty much the exact issue I was experiencing:

[React & nginx routing to subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53207059/react-nginx-routing-to-subdirectory)

So my final `./nginx/default.conf` looked like this:

```
server {
  listen 4001;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location = /new-admin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  location ~ ^/new-admin(.*) {
    try_files $1 $1/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```