# Deploy a React app built with vite and a basename to NGinx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, vite

I have a React app built using Vite that I intent to serve on Nginx at `www.example.com/myapp`

I've set `basename` in the React `Router` to `/myapp` and have set the `"homepage": "/myapp"` in `package.json` and it works great when I run vite dev server - the site is correctly scoped and served at `localhost:5173/myapp`.

However after running `vite build` and copying to my NGinx server, the linking doesn't work. Here is the location config which is based off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61490844/199) ...

```
location ^~ /myapp {
        // ...
        index index.html;
        alias /home/ubuntu/myrepo/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /myapp/index.html =404;
}
```

Weirdly, in the logs it does seem to be resolving to another root, `/usr/share/nginx/html/myapp/index.html` when there is not reference to `/usr/share/nginx/html` in any of my config.

It doesn't work though. I can only guess it is becuase `create-react-app` does something different to `vite build`?

Comment: It probably has no effect, but any reason to have `index index.html;` twice? Also where is `/home/ubuntu/myrepo/dist` in relation to `/usr/share/nginx/myapp`? Is `/home` really the root path? Inside `home` run `pwd` and see if it starts at `/home` or something else?

Comment: My mistake re `index.html` it isn't actually in there twice - `/home/ubuntu/myrepo/dist` is the repository in the `ubuntu` user home directory where the files are kept

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple of issues ...

Firstly, the resolving to another root was a red-herring - it turns out my NGinx config didn't have a resolver for non-HTTPS connections and I was connecting using `http://...`. To resolve this I just loaded the page with `https://...`.

Secondly, after a bit of digging, I found the [`base` setting for `vite`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#public-base-path) which only applies for building. This means the config looks like this ...

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '/myapp'
})
```

I also had to update some of my asset references when I was self-building the URL. I used `import.meta.env.BASE_URL` to get the stem. e.g.

`` const srcUrl = `${import.meta.env.BASE_URL}/assets/myimg.png ``

Hope that helps someone else

Answer (score 1):

You only have to have one index.html file in the root directory, vite makes all the indexation process for you.

To allocate *.jpg, *.png, etc, just put everything inside the public directory, there is where Vite looks at the external file references.
To look for the file just use "/" as the root path example:
public/pictures refer as /pictures in any *.jsx file and Vite do the rest