# Nginx proxy_pass on React app container not working

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I'm running a Nginx Docker container alongside some apps, including a React one.

So far, I've successfully setup the proxy_pass for all of them, except the React app.

The `default.conf` file specification for the pass is:

```
location /production {
    proxy_pass http://react-production:3000;
}
```

When the proxy_pass link has a `/` appended (`http://react-production:3000/`), it will return a blank page, otherwise I will just receive a page not found from React.

If I try to access the React app via it's IP and port manually it works fine, trying to do this by the pass route does not.

I guess it is also important to state that I'm using the React Router dependency, since it manages the routes of the app.

I tried reading a few articles about React deployment, and some stated that I have to change the `homepage` variable `package.json`:

`"homepage" : "/production"`

But it still didn't work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after lurking a bit more I found that this is not enough. You must also inform the Router the page where you'll be serving by adding `basename`

`<BrowserRouter basename="/production">` saved the day

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61490844/13296852) is where I found the correct answer